# Sync Calendar Between Two Exchange Services (OR Sync Google Calendar with Exchange 2007 through EWS)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, calendar

Where I work we have some people on an internal Exchange 2007 service and some people on Office 365.  This looks like it's not going to change anytime soon, and I need to be able to share my Office 365 calendar with people on the Exchange 2007 service.  I have an old account on the Exchange 2007 service that is no longer receiving email but does still have a calendar in there that can be shared with people on that service, and is accessible through EWS.  Is there some way to sync up (preferably two-way) my actively used Office 365 calendar with my mostly unused Exchange 2007 calendar?

As a partial solution, I found a way to sync up either one with Google calendar, but it requires that Outlook be set up to access that particular exchange service to work.  So far I've got the Office 365 calender actively syncing with Google calendar.  But I can't seem to find a way to also sync Exchange 2007 with that Google calendar without switching over Outlook to that service which of course would break everything else.  If I had a second computer inside the network that can be set up to access Exchange 2007 it would be a snap, but I don't.  Alternatively if there is a solution that can sync Exchange 2007 with Google calendar through EWS then I could set up my server at home to do that half of the job external to the network.

Any suggestions?  I've been Googling all sorts of variations on this problem for hours and I finally had to give up and ask for some help.